# Shortcode for making an image open in a fancybox (PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox, shortcode

I am facing a little problem in creating a shortcode using PHP on a custom CMS. I have created shortcodes in Wordpress with the help of tutorials but I am unable to find a tutorial on how to create shortcodes which would work outside of Wordpress. Basically, I am using a plugin which enables an image to appear in fullwidth inside a fancybox when clicked on it. Following is the code which generates the image and enables it to open in a fancybox when clicked on it:

```
<a class="fancybox" title="2009 Four Winns 318 Vista Tour" rel="gallery1" href="../../../../images/sampleboat/sam_0250.jpg"><img src="/wwwroot/userfiles/images/sam_0250.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200" /></a>
```

What I want to do is that I want to create a shortcode inside which I can just put the link to the image; something like this:

> [album src="../../../../images/sampleboat/sam_0250.jpg"]

and the function corresponding to this shortcode would insert the link, which is present inside the src="" tag of the shortcode, to the href="" and the src="" tags of this code:

```
<a class="fancybox" title="2009 Four Winns 318 Vista Tour" rel="gallery1" href="LINK FROM THE SHORTCODE"><img src="LINK FROM THE SHORTCODE" alt="" width="200" height="200" /></a>
```

So the functionality which I am trying to achieve is that I want to be able to enter this shortcode inside the text editor:

> [album src="../../../../images/sampleboat/sam_0250.jpg"]

and the code which I want to be echo'd out on the front page, corresponding to the shortcode added inside the page, is this:

```
<a class="fancybox" title="2009 Four Winns 318 Vista Tour" rel="gallery1" href="LINK FROM THE SHORTCODE"><img src="LINK FROM THE SHORTCODE" alt="" width="200" height="200" /></a>
```

Please let me know if there's any solution in order to achieve the above functionality. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The fancy term you are looking for is **Regular Expressions**. These can be used to check for patterns inside a string, and also to replace (parts of) one string with something else.

For your example, something like this will work:

```
$result =  preg_replace("/\[(.+)\]/", '<a class="fancybox" title="2009 Four Winns 318 Vista Tour" rel="gallery1" href="$1"><img src="$1" alt="" width="200" height="200" /></a>', $input);
echo $result;
```

In this case, "[something]" is replaced by the html code you specified above. the $1 will copy the part found between the first pair of () brackets of the regexp, thus in my example case, with: "something".

[read more about preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

I'd suggest reading up on regular expressions, as there is very much possible using them. They can be very confusing at times, however, as they have their own condensed syntax.